# getting error this.node(...) is null using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement javascript demo in `react`.

see vanila javscript demo is working fine
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-satoshi-s5dzs

but I am trying to implement same thing in `react` but getting this `error`
**this.node(...) is null**

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-driscoll-5cvmm

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="graph" />
      {d3
        .select("#graph")
        .graphviz()
        .renderDot(visualize(fsm))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: jsx compiles into code, not html immediately. i'd look at other d3 + react examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `html` element for `d3.select` , youse `refs`, and `useEffect` to select the element after the component is mounted : [Working sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-stonebraker-s04ne)

```
function App() {
  var fsm = new StateMachine({
    init: "open",
    transitions: [
      { name: "clodsdse", from: "open", to: "closed" },
      { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" }
    ]
  });

  var elem = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select(elem)
      .graphviz()
      .renderDot(visualize(fsm));
  }, [fsm, elem]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="graph" ref={e => elem = e}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035215/why-state-is-not-update-after-2-second