# How to update State after 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my view after two seconds. But it's not calling update view, why?

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-driscoll-5cvmm

Initial view is displayed but after two seconds it is not updating the DOM.

```
var fsm = new StateMachine({
    init: "open",
    transitions: [
      { name: "clodsdse", from: "open", to: "closed" },
      { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" }
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select("#graph")
      .graphviz()
      .renderDot(visualize(fsm));
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("---");
      update();
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think you should save your Graph data into your state, then in your `useEffect` hook, you can call `setFsm` to rerender your Graph.

You can also partially update your Graph data but in the following example I will just replace with your new Graph data instead.

You should also call `clearTimeout` in your `useEffect` return function to prevent memory leak in your app ( Just in case the component is unmounted before `setFsm` is called )

One thing I've realized on the previous answer is that, everytime `fsm` is updated, it will call `setTimeout` again, which result in `fsm` to update, which result in another `setTimeout`, essentially its like an endless loop. I've updated my answer so that the `setTimeout` is only called `onMount`, and another `useEffect` is just for rendering / updating the Graph. I think codes like this makes more sense.

You can use this code as your reference.

```
function App() {
  const [fsm, setFsm] = useState({
    init: "open",
    transitions: [
      { name: "clodsdse", from: "open", to: "closed" },
      { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
      { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" }
    ]
  });

  const renderGraph = () => {
    d3.select("#graph").graphviz().renderDot(visualize(new StateMachine(fsm)));
  };

  // for graph rendering after each update
  useEffect(renderGraph, [fsm]);

  // only setTimeout onMount and clearTimeout willUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setFsm({
        init: "open",
        transitions: [
          { name: "clodsdse", from: "open", to: "closed" },
          { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
          { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
          { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" },
          { name: "sasdss", from: "a", to: "bb" }
        ]
      });
    }, 2000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="graph" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has an edit history, you don't need to mention the edit manually in your answer.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Haha, just thought that giving some explanation on what I've edited would be nice :)

Comment: The edit is definitely good, but the "Update (11/25/2019):" only adds noise to your answer.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Okay thanks for point that out, updated my answer again :)

Answer (score 2):

I replace `window.d3` by only `d3` and it works.

```
const update = i => {
    var fsm = new StateMachine({
      init: "open",
      transitions: [
        { name: "clodsde" + i, from: "open", to: "closed" },
        { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
        { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
        { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" },
        { name: "sasdss", from: "a", to: "bb" }
      ]
    });
    d3.select("#graph")
      .graphviz()
      .renderDot(visualize(fsm));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.select("#graph")
      .graphviz()
      .renderDot(visualize(fsm));
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("---");
      update(i);
      i++;
    }, 2000);
```

Also I replace setTimeout by setInterval to update it every 2 sec.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `window.d3`, use `d3`:

```
 const update = () => {
    var fsm = new StateMachine({
      init: "open",
      transitions: [
        { name: "clodsdse", from: "open", to: "closed" },
        { name: "open", from: "closed", to: "open" },
        { name: "openss", from: "closed", to: "open" },
        { name: "ss", from: "a", to: "b" },
        { name: "sasdss", from: "a", to: "bb" }
      ]
    });
    d3 // <-- not window.d3
      .select("#graph")
      .graphviz()
      .renderDot(visualize(fsm));
  };
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-xnxmu)